# Form Data not returning data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

I am having trouble trying to figure out why I am unable to retrieve my form data. Below I have provided my work, I have added my view, viewmodel and controller. Please let me know if you need any additional information:

### ViewModel:

```
namespace Chargebacks.app.ViewModels
{
    public class ChargebackViewModel
    {
        public List<Fault> _TheFaults;
        public List<ChargebackStatu> _TheChargebackStatus;
        public List<Responsible> _TheResponsibleForChargeback;
        public List<Department> _TheDepartments;
        public GetChargeback_Result _TheCustomerChargeback;
    }
}
```

### View (Shortened):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Chargeback", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <h4 id="details">Summary</h4>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="HColor">
                    @Html.Label("Fault")
                </div>
                @Html.DropDownList("FaultName", new SelectList(Model._TheFaults, "Id", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
}
```

### Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(Chargeback model)
{
    var chargebackInDb = db.Chargebacks.Single(x=> x.Id == model.Id);
    if (chargebackInDb != null && ModelState.IsValid)
    {                
        chargebackInDb.FaultId = model.FactoryId;                
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Save");
}
```

I expect for it to return the values but it returns null instead.

Comment: The model parameter in the Action `public ActionResult Save` must be ChargebackViewModel, not Chargeback.

Comment: Or there's a missing model with just the selected faults that isn't shown.

Comment: @Jaggan_j I changed it to that but that didn't work either

Comment: @user6424058 - you probably have figured this out now, but just to clarify, what's the model in the View ?